# How to find deceleration of ball when deceleration causes speed to decrease which causes deceleration to decrease etc.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For my IB extended essay, I am modelling the trajectory of a tennis ball, however I later realised that the deceleration of the ball is not constant. Even if I found the initial speed and its initial deceleration, moments later that deceleration will cause the balls speed to decrease and thus causing the drag force decrease as well in a never ending loop until the ball has finally reached rest. I was wondering if there was a way I could solve this problem without making too many assumptions (I heard that maybe I should look into multi-variable calculus?).

Comment: do you know the formula in newtonian physics for distance under constant acceleration/deceleration ?

Comment: Multivariable calculus is the wrong extension of calculus for this kind of problem. You want (ordinary) differential equations.

Comment: Is the trajectory also influenced by gravity? I don't think there's a convenient closed-form solution in that case. You might have to look up numerical solution of differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to model acceleration as a function of velocity, then your problem is

$$
\frac {dv} {dt}  = f(v)
$$

Which is an *ordinary differential equation* and can be rearranged using *seperation of variables* to

$$
\int \frac{dv} {f(v)} = \int dt
$$

which you should be able to solve using 'normal calculus' provided you can integrate the LHS.

If you don't want to make too many assumptions about $f$ you could use *asymptomatic analysis* to, for example, find the low speed behaviour. You could do this by finding an expression that is asymptotically equal to $f$ as $v \rightarrow 0$ which can be though of as a low speed approximation to $f$, and then solving the problem for your approximation to $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model acceleration as a function of velocity, then your problem is

$$
\frac {dv} {dt}  = f(v)
$$

Which can be rearranged using seperation of variables to

$$
\int \frac{dv} {f(v)} = \int dt
$$

which you should be able to solve using 'normal calculus'.